# How to pass values to child Component vue and loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am using axios call to get values from API. 
I want to se Home and ListItem components. I want to

```js
<template>
    <div>
            <list-item v-for="idea in ideaList" :key="idea.id"></list-item>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import ListItem from '../components/ListItem'
    let AddIdea = require('../components/AddIdea.vue');
    export default {
        name: "HomePage",
        components: {AddIdea, ListItem},
        data() {
            return {
                addActive: "",
                ideaList: {},
                errors: {},
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.post('/getData')
                .then((response) => this.ideaList = response.data)
                .catch((error) => this.errors = error.response.data);
        },
    }
</script>
```

How to pass my IdeaList values to my ListItem component? And display them though loop. Where I am missing anything? I tried to insert propslike this:

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "ListItem",
    data() {
        return {
            props: ['idea']
        }
    }
}
```

and display value:

```
<template>
<span class="column is-8">
    {{idea.title}}
</span></template>
```

Where to look for how to make this work?

Comment: You have defined an `idea` prop in `ListItem` - why are you not using it?   `<list-item :idea="idea" v-for="idea in ideaList" :key="idea.id"></list-item>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want to pass complete `ideaList` or just iterated object to `ListItem`, but here are two obvious mistakes.

You've forgot to declare prop you want to pass to the `ListItem`

```
<list-item v-for="idea in ideaList" :key="idea.id" :idea="idea"></list-item>
```

In `ListItem` component, props shouldn't be declared inside `data` object

```
export default {
    name: "ListItem",
    props: ["idea"]
}
```